# Is Electron a good choice for an app dealing with a large amount of data?

Tags: performance, memory, electron

I'm working on a web app to download, decrypt, and create a report of a user's data. This report could be > 100 Gb with individual files of up to 5 Gb. The initial hope was to achieve this in the browser. But memory limitations, especially with a 5 Gb file, have scrapped this idea. Instead the new plan is to provide a standalone app to compile and download the report.

A suggestion has been put forward to use Electron. I'd like to know if this is viable? Or will Electron suffer from the same limitations as the browser?

Answer (score 1):

I'll provide my own response based on experience.

> I'd like to know if this is viable? Or will Electron suffer from the same limitations as the browser?

Electron has no such limits. It is perfectly capable of streaming large files and a large quantity of files. In our usage we validated it for 500 GBs and 12 million individual files.

There are other limits. For example if you add 100k+ files to a single zip, it takes a lot of time to extract. As such other strategies may be required. However this is not an Electron limitation.

One limitation of Electron that does matter is its lack of support for FIPS. i.e. Enterprise / Government level security. In our case it's omission means we need to re-write the client in C++. It was possible to get FIPS support on Linux. But this was only achieved using, with a good amount of effort, boringssl. As there are no boringssl releases for Windows we switched to C++.